# How to style a div on the home page like a blog post

Tags: css

I have a theme. Because I don't have a static home page, a list of my latest posts is my home page.

I want to add a drop-down box which I have coded on my starting home page which should remain static (just for home section).  For this, I tried to code it in `index.php`, but the problem is the box is outside that.  It is not coming up.  I mean that the post is wrapped in a box content, the same as I want for my drop-down menu.

Normally it is coming in simple line, but I want it to be wrapped in a box, like the posts.

I know that I just need to put a small `div` and `p` tag. I tried, but maybe my position is wrong,
can anyone help me here

Comment: What have your written so far? You're going to have to show some code if you want to get good help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `<div>` tag might solve your problem, however the `<div>` tag automatically puts in a line-return or break (`<br>`). I would suggest either positioning the `<div>` tag absolutely (Using position: absolute; in CSS), then float it right (Using float: right;).

Basically:

```
#div_el {
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
}
```

Should help a bit.